# Why is @Enitity required for @KeySpace enitity for spring-data-keyvalue

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-keyvalue

Following https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-key-value with Spring 3.1 and Java 17 I get and error where the Repo is not created unless I add @Enitity.  Why?  Is the blog wrong?  Did I find a defect?

Error without @Entity

> 2023-10-21T10:17:06.706-05:00  INFO 3536 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Map - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.example.demo.sql.Repo; If you want this repository to be a Map repository, consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.KeyValueRepository

pom.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>     <parent>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>         <version>3.1.5</version>
>         <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
>     </parent>
>     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
>     <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
>     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     <name>demo</name>
>     <description>demo</description>
>     <properties>
>         <java.version>17</java.version>
>     </properties>
>     <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
>             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
>             <scope>runtime</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
>
>     <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
> </project>
> ```

application.properties

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
> spring.datasource.username=sa
> spring.datasource.password=sa
> spring.h2.console.enabled=true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
> ```

```
package com.example.demo.sql;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.data.keyvalue.annotation.KeySpace;

@KeySpace
**@Entity**
public class KeyValue {
    @Id
    public String key;
    public String value;
}

package com.example.demo.sql;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<KeyValue, String> {
}

package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.sql.Repo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.map.repository.config.EnableMapRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMapRepositories
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public String bean(Repo repo) {
        return repo.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue/issues/541 the answer is that if I don't bring in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa then it worked without the `@Entity` annotation.  To build a key value repo with spring-data loaded is to use `KeyValueRepository` instead of `CrudRepository`.